# How to change the arrow length of a diagram using Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to change the arrow size of a diagram. I would like to have a small arrow. Looking at the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every text node part/.style={align=center}, 
]
\node (a) at (0,0) {Economically Liberal States};
\node[below=of a] (b) {Free Trade Policies};
\node[below=of b] (c) {Protect and Support Industries};
\node[left=of a] (d) {Karl Polanyi};
\draw[->] (d.east)--(a.west);
\draw[->] (a.south)--(b.north);
\draw[->] (b.south)--(c.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I got: 
[image]

I would like to get an arrow length like this one: 
[image]

Comment: I think you don't want to change the arrow length, but rather the distances between nodes. Try setting `node distance=1cm` as property of the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: Thank you @TeXnician. I didn't know it was the distance rather the length. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Distance rather than the length.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every text node part/.style={align=center}, node distance=0.3cm
]
\node (a) at (0,0) {Economically Liberal States};
\node[below=of a] (b) {Free Trade Policies};
\node[below=of b] (c) {Protect and Support Industries};
\node[left=of a] (d) {Karl Polanyi};
\draw[->] (d.east)--(a.west);
\draw[->] (a.south)--(b.north);
\draw[->] (b.south)--(c.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks to @TeXnician

Comment: Please, can you add the complete MWE? With Papeeria I have several errors. `Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function of' (in 'of a'). [\node[below=of a]]`.

Comment: @Sebastiano `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`

Comment: @Sebastiano Updated! :)

Comment: @MaximilianoRodriguez Ok!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!. Thanks to you and Ignasi. There is, but, another mode to build your picture with `tikz-cd`.